# What is the ListCell struct hold in an apacheAGE list?

Tags: postgresql, apache-age

Im using the debugger on apacheAGE to understand better the source code. Ive come across multiple times the `List` struct and the `ListeCell` struct, since they are very common in holding and fetching information.

Im having trouble what the `ListCell` struct holds as information. Everytime I access the values of a `ListCell` struct through gdb, I get some random values/numbers as a result.
I understand that since `ListCell` is a union, it may be possible that some of the fields dont make any sense since the memory is overwritten by another field, but still none of the 3 fields make any sense.

What is a way to decode those numbers to understand what information is being used each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that you are already familiar with the `List` struct and `ListCell` union of postgreSQL.

While you can view the `ListCell` content using GDB, please note that for Apache AGE, some of it may not appear meaningful as it is transformed and decoded.

I am sharing my GDB session below, which I hope could be of use to you.

**Query:**

```
SELECT * FROM cypher('test', $$
  WITH [1, 2, 3] AS c
  RETURN length(c)
$$) AS (res agtype);
```

**GDB:**

```
Breakpoint 1, list_length (l=0x5650776cecc0)
        at ../../../src/include/nodes/pg_list.h:91
    91      return l ? l->length : 0;
```

**List:**

```
(gdb) p l
$1 = (const List *) 0x5650776cecc0

(gdb) p *l
$2 = {type = T_List, length = 2, head = 0x5650776cecf8, tail = 0x5650776cec98}

// head: A pointer to an array of ListCell that store the actual data of elements of the list.

(gdb) p l->length
$3 = 2

// Because our list has 3 elements [1, 2, 3].
```

**ListCell:**

```
(gdb) p l->head
$4 = (ListCell *) 0x5650776cecf8

(gdb) p *l->head
$5 = {data = {ptr_value = 0x5650776cec08, int_value = 2003627016, oid_value = 2003627016}, next = 0x5650776cec98}

(gdb) p l->head->data->ptr_value
$6 = (void *) 0x5650776cec08

// ptr_value: A void pointer which holds our agtype data. So, we need to typecaste ptr_value to agtype pointer to see its content.

(gdb) p *(agtype*)l->head->data->ptr_value
$7 = {vl_len_ = 344, root = {header = 0, children = 0x5650776cec10}}

(gdb) p (*(agtype*)l->head->data->ptr_value)->vl_len_
$8 = 344

// _vl_len is varlena header (int32)

(gdb) p (*(agtype*)l->head->data->ptr_value)->root
$9 = {header = 0, children = 0x5650776cec10}

// root is agtype_container

(gdb) p *((agtype*)l->head->data->ptr_value)->root->children
$10 = 2003626560

// children is 28-bit agtentry
```